# Clojure loop/recur pattern, is it bad to use?

Tags: clojure

I'm in the process of learning Clojure, and I'm using [4Clojure](http://4clojure.com)
as a resource. I can solve many of the "easy" questions on the site, but for me thinking in a functional programming mindset still doesn't come naturally (I'm coming from Java). As a result, I use a loop/recur iterative pattern in most of my seq-building implementations because that's how I'm used to thinking.

However, when I look at the answers from more experienced Clojure users, they do things in a much more functional style. For example, [in a problem about implementing the range function](https://www.4clojure.com/problem/34), my answer was the following:

```
(fn [start limit]
  (loop [x start y limit output '()]
    (if (< x y)
      (recur (inc x) y (conj output x))
      (reverse output))))
```

While this worked, other users did things like this:

`(fn [x y] (take (- y x) (iterate inc x)))`

My function is more verbose and I had no idea the "iterate" function even existed. But was my answer worse in an efficiency sense? Is loop/recur somehow worse to use than alternatives? I fear this sort of thing is going to happen a lot to me in the future, as there are still many functions like iterate I don't know about.

Comment: if you swap to using vectors instead of lists, there's no need to reverse the final output. conj-ing onto a vector adds to the end. Try `(conj '(0) 1)` vs `(conj [0] 1)` to see the difference. So change to `output []` and drop the reverse at the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second variant returns a lazy sequence, which may indeed be more efficient, especially if the range is big.

The other thing is that the second solution conveys the idea better. To put it differently, it describes the intent instead of implementation. It takes less time to understand it as compared to your code, where you have to read through the loop body and build a model of control flow in your head.

Regarding the discovery of the new functions: yes, you may not know in advance that some function is already defined. It is easier in, say, Haskell, where you can search for a function by its type signature, but with some experience you will learn to recognize the functional programming patterns like this. You will write the code like the second variant, and then look for something working like `take` and `iterate` in the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

Bookmark the [Clojure Cheetsheet website](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html), and always have a browser tab open to it.

Study all of the functions, and especially read the examples they link to (the http://clojuredocs.org website).

The site http://clojure-doc.org is also very useful (yes, the two names are almost identical but not quite)

Answer (score 3):

The question should not be about performance (it depends!) but about communication: when using `loop/recur` or plain recursion or `lazy-seq` or sometimes even `reduce`, you make your code harder to understand: because the reader has to understand how you perform your iteration before getting to understand what you are computing.

Answer (score 1):

`loop`/`recur` is real Clojure, and idiomatic.  It's there for a reason.  And often there is no better way.  But many people find that once one gets used to it, it's very convenient to build many functions out of building blocks such as `iterate`.  Clojure has a very nice collection of them.  I started out writing things from scratch using truly recursive algorithms and then loop/recur.  Personally, I wouldn't claim that it's better to use the functional building blocks functions, but I've come to love using them.  It's one of the things that's great about Clojure.

(Yes, the many of the building block functions are lazy, as are e.g. `for` and `map`, which are more general-purpose.  Laziness can be good, but I'm not religious about it.  Sometimes it's more efficient.  Sometimes it's not.  Sometimes it's beautiful.  Sometimes it's a pain in the rear.  Sometimes all that.)

Answer (score 1):

Loop and recur are not bad - in fact, if you look at the source code for many of the built-in functions, you will find that is what they do - the provided functions are often an abstraction of common patterns which can make your code easier to understand. How you are doing things is typical for many when they first start. How you are approaching this seems correct to me. You are not just writing your solution and moving on. You are writing your solution and then looking at how others have solved the same problem and making a comparison. This is the right road to improvement. Highly recommend that when you find an alternative solution which seems more elegant/efficient/clear, analyse it, look at the source code of the built-in functions it uses and things will slowly come together.

Answer (score 1):

- `loop` ... `recur` is an optimisation for recursive tail calls, and should
  always be used where it applies.
- `range` is lazy, so your version of it should strive to be so.
  `loop` ... `recur` can't do this.
- All the sequence functions that can sensibly be lazy (`iterate`,
  `filter`, `map`, `take-while` ...) are so. As you know, you can use some of these
  to build a lazy `range`. As [@cgrand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32646229/1562315) explains, this is the preferred approach.

If you prefer, you can build a lazy `range` from scratch:

```
(defn range [x y]
  (lazy-seq
   (when (< x y)
     (cons x (range (inc x) y)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I wondered the same thing for some days but truly many tims I do not see any better alternative than loop recur. 
Some jobs are not fully "reduce" or "map". It is the case when you update data base on a buffer you mutates at every iteration.

Loop recur is very convienient where "non linear precise work" is require. It looks like more imperative but if I remember well Clojure was designed with pragmatism. Buy yet, pragmatism means choosing what is more effficient.

That is why in complex programs, I use both Clojure and java code mixed. sometimes java is just more clear for "low level" or iterative jobs like taking a specific value and so on while I see Clojure functions more useful for big data processing (without so much level of detail : global filters, etc.).

Some people say that we must stock with Clojure as much as possible but I do not see any reason not to use Java. I did not programmed a lot but Clojure/Java is the best interop I have ever seen, very complementary approaches.